# Adding unique, random 5 million rows to a table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

For MSSQL 2014, I need help in adding 5 million random rows to a table, with a varchar(25) pk column, the 2nd BIGINT & the 3rd nvarchar(256). How do I script this?

[So, I thought of populating values into Primary Key column and BIGINT Column at first. Every time I run a script for this, I get an error for Arithmetic overflow during datatype conversion.]

```
Create table Alok(Col1 varchar(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Col2 BIGINT NOT NULL, Col3 nvarchar(256))
--At first, just trying to insert values for PKColumn and BIGINT Column as couldn't script for all three columns at once.
DECLARE @RowCount INT
DECLARE @RowString VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @Random INT
DECLARE @Upper INT
DECLARE @Lower INT
DECLARE @InsertCol2 BIGINT

--To configure the items that are set once per run.
SET @Lower = 0
SET @Upper = 9223372036854775807
SET @RowCount = 0
--Setting up the RowCount
WHILE @RowCount < 5000000
BEGIN
SET @RowString = CAST(@RowCount AS VARCHAR(25))

SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)

SET @InsertCol2 = ROUND(((@Lower + 9000000000) * RAND()), 15)

INSERT INTO Alok
    (Col1
    ,Col2)

VALUES
    (REPLICATE('0', 25 - DATALENGTH(@RowString)) + @RowString
    , @InsertCol2)

SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1
END
```

Comment: Please include the script

Comment: Even if you get this to work it's going to take days to finish.

Comment: Yes! This kept on executing for over 2 hours and then I just stopped it and tried to run it by limiting the RowCount to 100 to check if it is going to even work. And, then I received an error for datatype conversion.

Comment: First, you must insert values to all columns as none of them allows null and none of them have a default value. Second, why do you need to insert 5 million random records in the first place?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I did get an error for leaving Col3 empty so I modified my table and allowed NULL values for now in my 3rd column. Reason for 5 million rows insertion: This table will be used in Production and hence I need to prepare it as per the requirements furnished. There will be records getting added to it so I am trying to add sample data to stress test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting 5,000,000 rows row-by-agonizing-row in auto commit transactions is going to take ages.

This solves the problem by simply removing the parts that cause the error and should execute much quicker.

```
INSERT INTO Alok
            (Col1,
             Col2)
SELECT TOP (5000000) FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID), 'D25'),
                     ABS(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS BIGINT))
FROM   master..spt_values v1,
       master..spt_values v2
```

Comment: Thank You Martin! This one got executed much faster. But, now if I also have to populate the 3rd varchar(256) column, I am little confused as to how can I alter your script. Could you please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first arithmetic overflow:

```
DECLARE @Upper INT
...
SET @Upper = 9223372036854775807
```

If you change that to BIGINT, this is the second one:

```
DECLARE @Random INT
...
SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
```

Once you change those to bigint's, the insert should start succeeding